# Django: All Static Files 404 (but findstatic is able to locate them)

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I just started a fresh Django project and added in my static files to try and load my template.

However, all of my staticfiles are giving me a 404 error whenever I load my template.

When i use findstatic, though, it is successful:

```
(AlmondKing) C:\Projects\AlmondKing>python manage.py findstatic images/logo.png  --verbosity 2

Found 'images/logo.png' here:
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\InventoryLogs\static\images\logo.png
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\FinancialLogs\static\images\logo.png
Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\static
  C:\Users\Adam\Envs\AlmondKing\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\InventoryLogs\static
  C:\Projects\AlmondKing\AlmondKing\FinancialLogs\static
```

This is driving me up the wall. I've tried placing the static files in all relevant locations, but it won't grab them via runserver. Any ideas as to what the culprit could be?

My settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'AlmondKing.InventoryLogs',
    'AlmondKing.FinancialLogs',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: Add some info about how you are trying to access static files in your template & what does the firebug (or other inspector) say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the prompting from chem1st, I converted the template to the {% loadstatic %} syntax in the template which is currently [recommended in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).

It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to

```
$ manage.py collectstatic
```

..

you also would need to set a STATIC_ROOT